# MATLAB how can I save an image?

Tags: matlab, autosave

I tried the commands:

```
 imshow(originalImage);
 imsave;
```

it works, but I want the matlab to automatically save the image in bmp format (in the current folder).
I tried to use:

```
 save('myimage.bmp','originalImage');
```

the picture was saved, but on the image itself, instead of the picture, I saw this message:
"windows photo viewer can't open this picture because the file apears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large".
(the size of the picture is 5kb).

Thanks!

Comment: The EDIT button is for adding more details to your question, not asking an entirely different one.  -1.  I will revert the change, you are welcome to click the "Ask Question" button to start a new question.  Linking between questions is also encouraged.  Adding new problems to a previous question is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function `imwrite` to do that:

```
imwrite(image_matrix, 'myimage.bmp', 'bmp')
```

[imwrite documentation on mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html)

Comment: the image size after saving it by imwrite is 110kb, when I'm saving the image by imshow the size is 540kb. If I use a specific function on the saved image of the first way, it doesn't work, and on the second way it works. there is an action to automatically save the picture but size of 540kb? thank you!

Comment: I really didn't understand what you mean, try to restate that more clearly

Comment: saving with file->save as saves the whole picture AS SHOWN on the screen. With imwrite (or imsave) you save only the picture itself. Read the docs, it's always a good idea, and you end up learning some interesting stuff ;).

Comment: there is a way to save the picture manually:
    imshow(image);
and then click 'file' -> 'save as' and save the image in bmp format. By this way, the image was saved with size of 540kb.
the automatically way to save the picture(imwrite) saved the image in bmp format, by the size of the picture is 110kb.
I have a function that I wrote, and if I run the function on the image that I saved by the first way(manually), the function works well. But if I run the function on the image that was saved automatically, the function doesn't work. why please?
thanks again.

Comment: man, I cannot possibly imagine WHY it does not work, I don't know what's the error, I don't know what you are doing, try to investigate that yourself, debug your code, be creative, and, if after doing that, you still cannot figure out, post another question here and I'm pretty sure someone will help you. But do your homework and try for yourself, you will learn a lot in the process

Comment: I was trying about 2 days, but I try more, thank you very much :]